# How to show popup after a specific time of no interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

When a page opens I want to show a popup in that page after 2 minutes. In the same page I have 3 buttons. When I revisit the page in less than 2 minutes and I click any one button I want to reset the timer. See the explanation below.

1. I have `index.html`. In that page I have 3 buttons like so `button1`, `button2` and `button 3`.
2. If the user does **not** click any button in that page within 2 minutes popup will appear with a message "Your time is over".
3. If the user click any button within the 2 minutes, the timer should be reset to 0.

Can anyone please help me? I tried different code but it's not useful.

Comment: Share some code that you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner is too demanding without basic knowledge of the concepts involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` and cancel the timeout using `clearTimeout`, example:

```js
var resetButton =$('#resetButton')[0],timerId;

function timerExpired() {
    alert('Timer expired');
}

$(resetButton).click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, 5000);
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are the buttons, you should reset the timer on click of a button

Comment: updated with buttons

Comment: In stackoverflow we can help you, but not do you work. Please look ak the example and analize whats happening and adjust to your code. You didn't provide any code @Ramanji

Comment: @Drusto that's exactly why you shouldn't have bothered answering this question

Comment: Not sure about the use of `var btn = $("#btn")[0];  $(btn)` - why not keep the first jquery object `var btn = $("#btn")`  you can still use `$(btn)` (ie `$($("#btn"))`) with no adverse effects